# CSS Specificity: Unexpected behaviour

Tags: css, css-specificity

I have been following [this article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) on CSS specifity. It assigns values to selectors and the selector with the highest sum of values will have precedence.

An id has a value of 100.
a class has a value of 10.

My problem is in this example I tried.

HTML

```
<div id="id" class="a b c d e f g h i j k l">What color?</div>
```

CSS

```
/* calculated specificity: 100 */
#id{
    color:red;
}

/* calculated specificity: 120 */
.a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.j.k.l{
    color:green;
}
```

I expected the div to be green since 12 classes would have a value of 120. But it is red when I run it. Is there a problem with my calculation?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VnLLb/2/)

Comment: In that article, it has a CSS specificity for poker players (which is neat), and it specifically says: `Just as any three-of-a-kind beats any pair, CSS rules with ID selectors beat rules with any number of class selectors.` so it doesn't matter if you have 20 classes, ID trumps it.

Comment: @SLoW so the whole concept of assigning values and summing them is a bit pointless if id always beats class. Is that right?

Comment: yeah, personally I wouldn't bother with assigning a bunch of classes just to override and ID assignment.  I'd just give it a different ID and save yourself some trouble. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ID trumps class specificity as [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> The following list of selectors is by increasing specificity:
>
> - Universal selectors
> - Type selectors
> - Class selectors
> - Attributes selectors
> - Pseudo-classes
> - ID selectors
> - Inline style

The specificity calculation can be a bit confusing, but you need to remember, as the [W3 states](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity), that when calculating the specificity that you concatenate, not add the numbers together.

So for example:

- #id has a specificity = 0,1,0,0
- .a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.j.k.l has a specificity = 0,0,12,0

So yes, the ID will trump the pure class selection every time.

Comment: As euchre fan I +1 for the use of trump

Comment: In that case, is it fair to say that the value system is flawed?

Comment: @Sionnach733 - I added a little more explanation to my answer.